# After using sef link pictures has gone

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is the question

my products page has this url - `example.com/products.php?id=5&page=yzf-r-125`

I want to rewrite the url to - `example.com/motorcycles/super-sport/yzf-r-125-5.html`

I have added the following rule to the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)$ products.php?id=$4&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

to link manually first and second variables like :

```
<a href=<php echo $category>/<php echo $subcategory>/<php echo $product>-
  <php echo $id> > (i know this code wrong i hope you understand what i mean )
```

The URL works when I enter `example.com/motorcycle/super-sport/yzf-r-125-5`

However the links and images are broken. Example

broken image url : `example.com/motorcycle/super-sport/images/image.png`
but my image route: `example.com/images/image.png`

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a relative URI base in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Or change your image links to absolute URLs:

```
<img src="/images/image.png">
```

Comment: Or fix the url rewrite

Comment: advice would be to try what jon lin wrote ;)

Comment: @Ryan There's nothing wrong with the rule, it's not getting applied to images. Relative links to images will make the browser mistake the URI base when the image is linked from a URL like `example.com/motorcycles/super-sport/yzf-r-125-5.html`, which has a URI base of `/motorcycles/super-sport/`, which is why `imaegs/image.png` gets appended to that instead. The browser doesn't know that there's some internal-to-the-server rewriting happening, it just sees the URL of the resource that it just sent a request for.

Answer (score 0):

I would prepend the rewrite rule with condition to rewrite an url only if the resource does not exixts

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)$ products.php?id=$4&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

Leaving the html untouched